# ¿Forma óptima de llamar un método No-estático de una activity desde una clase AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

No sé si mi pregunta sea adecuada pero tengo la siguiente duda:

Tengo una clase que extiende de `AsyncTask` y ejecuta operaciones con base de datos, en `PostExecute()` necesito ejecutar un método de una Activity, pero dicho método ***NO es estático***, y no puedo acceder a el desde el contexto estático de mi AsyncTask.

***Creo que hay 2 posibles soluciones:***

- Convertir mi método a estático en la Activity.

  ó
- Pasar la Activity como argumento al ejecutar la clase AsyncTask.

**¿Cuál es la forma más óptima de hacerlo y por qué?**